# Classpath in Manifest

Tags: java

I have download a xSocket.jar which will be use as a classpath and compile myprogram.jar, both are in Java folder.
Is adding a classpath in Manifest able to find xSocket.jar without the need to define a `-cp` in commandline?

In my commandline `D:\>` location, I tried running `java -jar java\myprogram.jar -n 0`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xsocket/connectio
n/IBlockingConnection
        at myprogram.main(myprogram.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xsocket.connection.IBlockingCon
nection
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 1 more
```

My Manifest in myprogram.jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_22 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: myprogram
Class-Path: xSocket
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the full jar file name i.e. with extension. Check [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) for more information.

```
Class-Path: xSocket.jar
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! No wonder, I been spending 2 days to get my Flash application NativeProcess to work as it has a bug that is unable to execute Jar with -cp correctly. But can I declare classpath in absolute path? Such as "D:\java\xSocket.jar" without the double quote?

Answer (score 1):

> Is adding a classpath in Manifest able
>   to find xSocket.jar without the need
>   to define a -cp in commandline?

Yes, it's the way.

You should change your class pass value in `myprogram.jar` to

`Class-Path: relatedPath/xSocket.jar`

Comment: hmm, if both jar are in the same folder mean I still must add relatedPath? why?

Comment: @user217582: if both jars are in the same folder then the relative path is an empty string (and slash is not needed of course). Btw, different jars are separated by space.

Comment: Great, I have another question, what if I have to declare 2 or more classpath by different folders, how can it be done? and how can I declare for multiple jar too? Using *" an asterisk with a double quote? Sorry, I a bit lazy at reading Java since I am busy with lot of Actionscript projects.